# How to finish current activity and go back to previous fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

An “ADD” button in fragment calls the activity. By pressing “Done” button on this activity, I want to send data using bundle to previous fragment and closes this activity.

The problem I face is, on “Done” button click in activity nothing happens.

Fragment:

```
btnAddSkills.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), SkillActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("caller","editprofile");
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("userskills", (ArrayList<Skill>) userskills);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Activity:

```
btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        EditProfileFragment epf = new EditProfileFragment();
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putParcelableArrayList("newskills", (ArrayList<Skill>) newskills);
                        epf.setArguments(args);
                        fm.popBackStackImmediate();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use start activity for result

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), SkillActivity.class);
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString("caller","editprofile");
       bundle.putParcelableArrayList("userskills", (ArrayList<Skill>) userskills);
       intent.putExtras(bundle);
       startActivityForResult(intent,122);// you can change this number
```

and in your activity which hold the fragment add this implementation to pass the result to the fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and in Done button

```
btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putParcelableArrayList("newskills",  
 (ArrayList<Skill>)newskills); 
 returnIntent.putExtras("result", args);                          
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();                      
      }
});
```

finaly implment this in your fragment to recive the data

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(requestCode == 122 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
   Bundel bundle=data.getExtras();
   String caller=data.getString("caller");
   ArrayList<Skill> skills=data.getParcelable("userskills");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use interface to share data b/w activity and fragment.check this [here](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/fragment-to-fragment-communication-with-shared-viewmodel)